# Passing double value for coordinates in .NET Core MVC 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, double, coordinates

I struggle with issue to pass value for double property. As property regards coordinates (Latitude, Longitude) their format will be ###.######. On my PC default numeric format is ### ###,##
My input field pass only values ###,###. If put something different like:

1234,444 then I receive message "The field Latitude must be a number." and in code property got value 0

130.653221  =>the same, property receive 0 and I got message "The value '130.653221' is not valid for Latitude."

12,1234 then client validator won't pass me because "The field Latitude must be a number."

I tried to put regular expression in ViewModel e.g. [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,6}$")] but unsuccessful.
Is there any way to change format of value to ###.######?

Below you can find my code:

ViewModel

```
    public class ShopLocationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string FirstText { get; set; }
    public string SecondText { get; set; }
    public string ThirdText { get; set; }
    public string LinkText { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind("Header,FirstText,SecondText,ThirdText,LinkText,Link,Latitude,Longitude,Priority,Id")] ShopLocationViewModel shopLocation)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var shopLocationDto = _viewModelMapper.Map(shopLocation);
            _dataManger.AddNewShopLocation(shopLocationDto);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(shopLocation);
    }
```

View:

```
@model ShopLocationViewModel

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Header" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Header" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Header" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstText" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstText" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstText" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SecondText" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="SecondText" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="SecondText" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ThirdText" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ThirdText" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ThirdText" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LinkText" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LinkText" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LinkText" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Link" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Link" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Link" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Latitude" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Latitude" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Latitude" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Longitude" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Longitude" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Longitude" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Priority" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Priority" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Priority" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}}
```

Comment: Search following page for Culture : https://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/

Comment: You cannot have a latitude greater than 90 degrees. The North Pole is at 90 degrees - so no wonder you got "The value '130.653221' is not valid for Latitude."

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are right about Latitude but as you can see in code I don't limit property to coordinates as it's regular double so 130.653221 should be valid anyway

Comment: Can you share your default numeric format on your pc,I test your code,and I  get 1234,444=>1234444,130.653221=>130.653221,12,1234=>121234